# If Goldbach's conjecture is false, is it possible that there are only a finite number of failing cases?

Tags: number-theory, goldbachs-conjecture

If Goldbach's conjecture is false, is it possible that there are only a finite number of failing cases?

I know it is probably unknown, but any reference to something addressing this question would be apreciated.

Comment: Currently, every finite number of failures is possible (of course most likely is "$0$ failures") and I think we cannot even rule out inifnite many failures.

Answer (score 2):

You may wish to have a look at section 3.2 of Vaughan's *The Hardy-Littlewood Method*, where he proved that

**Theorem:** Let $E(x)$ denote the number of even numbers $\le x$ that cannot be written as a sum of two primes. Then for all $A>0$, there exists a constant $C(A)>0$ such that for large $x$:

$$
E(x)<C(A){x\over\log^Ax}
$$

This might not be the best possible bound as the book was published in the 1980s.